# can invoke concrete class method using interface without casting

Tags: java, interface

here's the code snippet.

```
public interface Parent{
    public void invoke();
}

public class Child implements Parent{

    public void invoke(){
         System.out.println("invoking invoke()");
    }

    public void invoke1(){
         System.out.println("invoking invoke1()");
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args){

      Parent parent = new Child();
      parent.invoke1();
}
```

how would i invoke invoke1() using interface without casting it to child?

Comment: You can't. You have to cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how would i invoke invoke1() using interface without casting it to child?

Not possible. And that's one leg of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. invoke1() method is not belonging to the Parent interface. That method method is owned by the child class. so in order to invoke the method, you need to have a need to have a valid object reference for the Child class.